# Android ValueAnimator not working

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-animation, android-view

I have this working code in my AsyncTasks class.

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
        View view = (View) values[0];
        view_group.addView(view);

        view.animate().y(500).setDuration(1000);
    }
```

I tried to change the code to this:

```
protected void onProgressUpdate(Object... values) {
            View view = (View) values[0];
            view_group.addView(view);

            ValueAnimator va = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(view, "y", 500);
            va.setDuration(1000);
            va.start();
            }
```

The View is appearing, but not animated.

What am I missing?

**Edit:**

I also tried to put the ValueAnimator code inside an `AnimatorListener` (with different coordinates of course), so it will run after the first animation finishes, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What am I missing?

The `x` and `y` are `float` values and not `int` so use:

```
ValueAnimator va = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, "y", 500);
```

or if you're targeting `ICS` you could use:

```
ValueAnimator va = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(view, View.Y, 500);
```

Comment: Can't believe I've missed that, and had to spent HALF of my reputation points :)))).. But it was worth it :). Thanks.